# How to eliminate go get dependency check?

Tags: go

When I exec `go get -u github.com/spf13/viper`, which has a dependency `golang.org/x/sys`.It will auto-execute `cd ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys; git pull --ff-only`.

This is really extra no use.

My network can't reach golang.org/x/sys. So I've already used `github.com/golang/sys` and put it into my `GOPATH/src/golang.org/x`.Which means the auto-check(`cd ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys; git pull --ff-only`) for the progress(`go get -u github.com/spf13/viper`) should be totally eliminated, because it stuck my jenkins deploy time.

More than 90% time of jenkins deployment is wasted in checks like

`cd ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys; git pull --ff-only`

`cd ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/text; git pull --ff-only`

...

Here is part of my jenkins log:

```
# cd /home/tonnn/go/src/golang.org/x/sys; git pull --ff-only
fatal: unable to access 'https://go.googlesource.com/sys/': Failed connect to go.googlesource.com:443; Connection timed out
package golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1

# cd /home/tonnn/go/src/golang.org/x/text; git pull --ff-only
fatal: unable to access 'https://go.googlesource.com/text/': Failed connect to go.googlesource.com:443; Connection timed out
```

So, is there a way to only get `viper` but do not check its dependencies?

`viper` is only an example to show my question.I bet most of you have met this kind of question.

I'm using Go 1.9.

Comment: I have removed your unrelated question about upgrading Go. If you need help with that, ask a separate question, and actually explain the problem you're having.

Comment: To answer your question: You should probably vendor your dependencies, if you're working in an environment without network access.

Answer (score 0):

Embarassed to answer the question myself but I do find its solution.

When `${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys` already exists before you fetch from `github.com/golang/sys`.It will jump this stage and cause an occasion that when you execute `git remote -v`.It will list origin `https://go.googlesource.com/sys fetch/push`.This is exactly what causes my stuck `fetch googlesource.com/sys time out`.

Ok,Now there is two way to fix it.

First way, remove existed package and make it exactly fetched from github.com/golang/sys.
`rm -rf ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys`.After jenkins shell jobs, its git remote will correctly convert to `https://github.com/golang/sys`

Second way, change its origin remote.

```
cd ${GOPATH}/src/golang.org/x/sys
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/golang/sys.git
```

Hope it helpful to all of you.